# Check if name already exist in database but Id is not same in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Properties Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

I want to check if the name exists during edit but if it is the same Property then ignore it.

When I want to insert using this code

```
$ruls = [
        'property_type' => 'required',
        'project_name' => 'required|unique:properties,name',
    ];
$request->validate($ruls, []);
```

and I want to using same validation when property edit like

```
select name from properties where name = name and id != 1
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your validation, you can define a rule to check name unique with id like this

```
$ruls = [
    'property_type' => 'required',
    'project_name' => 'required|unique:properties,name'.$id.',id',
];
$request->validate($ruls, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the current ID in question when updating:

```
$ruls = [
        ...
        'project_name' => [required, Rule::unique('properties', 'name')
         ->ignore($id)],

    ];
$request->validate($ruls, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unique rule with ignore the id. Something like this:

```php
$rules = [
    'property_type' => 'required',
    'property_name' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('properties', 'name')->ignore($property->id),
     ],
]
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique